# Unable to append String to array in Swift

Tags: swift

So I am using this code and I get the error: Immutable value of type 'Array' only has mutating members named 'append.' I have been unable to find any working solutions as of yet.

```
import Foundation
struct Roster
{
    var names: Array<String>  = []

    func add(name: String) {
        names.append(name)
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the rule of immutable struct in swift, if you want to be able to modify the properties inside a method, you have to mark the method as mutating.

```
struct Roster
{
    var names: Array<String>  = []

    mutating func add(name: String) {
        names.append(name)
    }
}
```